# When training a network model in the background in windows, the training speed becomes slower and the time increases

Tags: windows, deep-learning, training-data

I use python to write a deep neural network model and train it in Windows11. During the process of running the program using vscode and pycharm, I found that when the program was switched to the background, the training speed slowed down and the training time increased.

For example, when my current window is switched from vscode to the edge browser and stays there for a few minutes, the training of vscode slows down, and the cooling fan does not make any sound, which indicates that the GPU is resting; and when I switch back to vscode, the cooling fan is spinning rapidly, which indicates that the GPU is working.

The following is the record obtained by the same program after multiple experiments:

```
order=000, avg_psnr=33.275, cur_time: 2023-11-15 19:46:29
order=001, avg_psnr=33.584, cur_time: 2023-11-15 19:56:36
order=002, avg_psnr=33.388, cur_time: 2023-11-15 20:01:05
order=003, avg_psnr=33.493, cur_time: 2023-11-15 20:06:26
order=004, avg_psnr=33.581, cur_time: 2023-11-15 20:13:29
order=005, avg_psnr=33.410, cur_time: 2023-11-15 20:17:28
order=006, avg_psnr=33.253, cur_time: 2023-11-15 20:27:00
order=007, avg_psnr=33.232, cur_time: 2023-11-15 20:30:35
```

In each experiment, the parameters of the network are the same. In theory, if the same CPU and memory resources are allocated, the running time should be very close each time. But in the above records, the time spent in each experiment varies greatly, sometimes as long as 10 minutes, and sometimes only 3 minutes.

I would like to know a way to keep the network training at a stable speed without increasing the network training time due to program switching.